# My malloc doesn't update the heap properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own malloc and then test it by dumping the heap to see what I've managed to accomplish. It compiles fine but when I run it, I get the output of

```
head->[1:0:8]->NULL
this is a test program
```

after which it promptly crashes. It looks like the way I implemented my malloc, it is able to allocate the space for *this and *is, but that's all. Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

My main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>


#define MALLOC(n) my_malloc(n)
#define DUMP_HEAP() dump_heap()
void* my_malloc(int);

int main()
{
  char *this = MALLOC(5);
  char *is = MALLOC(3);
  char *a = MALLOC(2);
  char *test = MALLOC(5);
  DUMP_HEAP();

  strcpy(this, "this");
  strcpy(is, "is");
  strcpy(a, "a");
  strcpy(test, "test");
  strcpy(program, "program");
  printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", this, is, a, test, program);
  DUMP_HEAP();

  return 0;
}
```

My malloc.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct Block 
{
    int occ;             
    int size;            
    struct Block *prev;   
    struct Block *next;  
};

static struct Block *head = NULL; 

void *my_malloc(int size)
{
    void *pointer;
    pointer = (void*)sbrk(size);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
            head = pointer;
            head->occ = 1;
            head->prev=NULL;
            head->next=NULL;
            head->size = size;

            return (void*)head+sizeof(struct Block);
    }
    else
    {
            struct Block* new ;
            new = pointer;
            head->next = new;
            new->size = size;
            new->occ = 1;
            new->prev = head;
            new->next = NULL;
            head = new;

            return (void*)new+sizeof(struct Block);
    }
}

void dump_heap()
{
  struct Block *cur;
  printf("head->");
  for(cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) 
  {
    printf("[%d:%d:%d]->", cur->occ, (char*)cur - (char*)head, cur->size);
    assert((char*)cur >= (char*)head && (char*)cur + cur->size < (char*)sbrk(0));
    if(cur->next != NULL) assert(cur->next->prev == cur); 
  }
  printf("NULL\n");
}
```

Comment: High time to use a debugger.

Comment: ummmm... how do you define `program`?

Comment: `pointer = (void*)sbrk(size);` --> `pointer = (void*)sbrk(sizeof(*head)+size);` ? Also `(void*)head+sizeof(struct Block);` --> `(void*)(head+1);`

Comment: `sizeof(head)` is pointer size, not size of  `struct Block`. Also Do not change the question code directly after posting it. (I did rollback)

Comment: Please don't edit question by fixing error in code, that destroy potential answer.

Comment: Your code to add a node at the front of the linked list is not correct, either. It should be `head->prev = new; new->prev = NULL; new->next = head; head = new;` If you are careful not to dereference a null `head`, you don't need the separate codes for the first and subsequent nodes.

Comment: I think the intention of this code is actually that `head` represents the `tail` of the linked list.  This is its own problem, but it means that the code is functionally correct and the variable is misnamed.  `head` should be a variable that is initialized only if NULL, and updated only when the first block is `free`d.

Comment: @Matt: The linked-list code as given is not "functionally correct". The lines `head->next = new` and `head = new` alone are glaringly wrong.

Comment: @MOehm Rename the variable `head` to `tail`.  `tail->next = new` followed by `tail = new` generates an in-tact linked list.  That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @MOehm because the `head` is functioning as the `tail`.  This means that `malloc` is functionally correct but `dump_heap` has a bug where it's using the tail of the linked list, incorrectly named `head`. :)

Comment: @Matt: Okay, but then you lose the `head` or you should be iterating via the `prev` pointer, which the code above doesn't, and that's why the iteration stops at the first node. (It's doubtful if `prev`/`next` makes sense in a non-circular list without both`head` and ´tail`.)

Comment: Updated my answer to account for this discussion.  Yes, you do lose the `head`, but the only ill effect is the bug making `dump_heap` incorrect.  It will definitely come back to bite @Fox when they go to write `free`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't accounting for the size of the `Block` struct when asking the system for memory.

Compare this line:

```
pointer = (void*)sbrk(size);
```

to how you're attempting to account for the struct later:

```
return (void*)head+sizeof(struct Block);
```

You should be accounting for the size of the `Block` in the sbrk call:

```
pointer = (void*)sbrk(size + sizeof(struct Block));
```

Also, as has been pointed out, you should not do pointer arithmetic on `void*`.  So your return statements should leave the `head` pointer uncasted and just add 1 to account for the block size:

```
return (void*)(head + 1);
```

Also also, upon further discussion it is clear that `head` is being used as the tail of the linked list.  This introduces a bug in `dump_heap`.  You may want to rename `head` to `tail` and maintain a proper `head`, one which only ever changes in `malloc` when it was previously `NULL`.

Comment: you can't use `void *` with arithmetic because what is the size of void ? Use `char *` or `return head + 1;` cause type of `head` is `struct Block *`